# view individual records on mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: database]

here is the screen shot of my database! i have successfully done the insert and delete action
however i have problem in viewing  individual records
when i click view on id #45 all the details will display including the second row! here is the screen shot of the result

[image: result]

as you can see in the result the detail in 2nd row appear! i want to display only the details of the row that i clicked!
i would ask assistance from you expert

here is my view.php code

```
<?php
require 'database.php'; 

$query = "SELECT id, date, po FROM sales";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));   

if ($result) {
  echo "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='15' border='0'>
    <th >Date</th><th >PONumber</th>";
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $po        = $row->po;
    $date      = $row->date;               
    $id        = $row->id;
    echo "<tr>
     <td>$date</td> <td >$po</td></tr>";  
  }      
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the HTML for that first table look like? Specifically, what do the links do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php code is looping through all rows returned by $query. Your query probably has a bad where clause

Edit for your Edit:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = "SELECT id, date, po FROM sales where id = $id";
```

Comment: This should go without saying, but this is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Make sure you understand the implications before you put code like this live. Make sure you use some sort of sanitizing function on $id before running that query.

Comment: wow it works perfectly!Thank you so much Andrew Edvalson! i have to work on the edit next! thanks so much andrew

Answer (score 1):

Your `$query` command is too general. Right now, it is saying "Select the fields id, date, and po from the sales table." What you want to do is say "Select the fields id, date, and po from the sales table only for those entries which have id = the id selected on the page before". This would be something like

`$query = "SELECT id, date, po FROM sales WHERE id = ".$id`

where the $id value is the properly escaped input id. You are probably sending this id via GET, so it will be something like $_GET['id'], but this depends, as Michael said, on what the HTML for the first table looks like.

This is important: you don't want to just use this the way I have illustrated it above without properly escaping the data you received from GET, otherwise someone could erase the whole table by sending SQL in through the value of $_GET['id']. Look into this method:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/escape-variables-php-pear-db-bound-placeholders/

This will assist you in properly escaping the data. The answer to your question, however, is that you must add that `WHERE` clause.